# How to update all blocks in a chunk?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-worldedit, mcedit

I am making a Minecraft map and I now have lots of unupdated water blocks that need to be updated for proper flow. Placing and removing blocks isn't an option because these bodies of water are too large.

Is there any way to cause block updates for every block in a chunk? I can use WorldEdit and MCEdit, and also Bukkit plugins.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unable to test this right now, but what might work with World Edit is to replace the water with something else and then to make it water again (`//replace water diamondblock` followed by `//replace diamondblock water`).

If I remember correctly that caused a block update.

If that doesn't work try replacing the air surrounding the water in the same manner (`//replace 0 diamondblock`, `//replace diamondblock 0`).

Of course, if it's supposed to be a pool there is the handy dandy [/fixwater](http://wiki.sk89q.com/wiki/WorldEdit/Utilities#Fixing_pools).

Comment: `/fixwater` seems like the best option to me.  It does exactly what is says on the box.

Comment: True, but if you want, say, a bunch of fountains, it'd just make some weird pool-like things.

Answer (score -3):

There is an update command in worldedit: //regen you can only use this in bukkit not sp

[here](http://wiki.sk89q.com/wiki/WorldEdit/Reference) are all comands if you need it

Comment: `//regen` regenerates the selected chunk. That is not what I want. I only want the blocks to be updated. Thanks for trying to help, though.

Comment: Maybe the "alt-f3" will do. google if it is still in because i don't know. this trick is vanilla if you wonder